# How to convert ARCore frames to WebRTC frames

Tags: arcore, webrtc-android

I'm making a video call android app with augmented face effects using ARCore and WebRTC.

However, the frame structure of WebRTC and ARCore is different.

So I use PixcelCopy to convert ARCore frames to Bitmap and then convert them to WebRTC frames.

However, the audio and video are out of sync with this method.

Is there any other way?

Any advice would be of great help to me

thanks